# How to implement digital zooming in video with iphone device camera?

Tags: iphone, ios4

In an iPhone App, I have to implement a feature such that user can make video through iPhone app and digitally zoom it also. Digital zoom feature should work while making videos. Any ideas how can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling). Bilinear is common because its fast (but the results are low quality).